# c# WinForm App setup wizard w/ network DB and multi Cient

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have been searching for this for couple days but was unlucky finding any answer.
 I am building a winform application . Where the application will be installed to multi PC's on the same network  and all will connect to the db on the server in same network.

First , I am unable to find how to develop/design multi client(sorry I don't know what exactly to call it ) application , where same app will be operating at the same time, with different users, in different PC's and all will use the a single  DB on the network.

Second , I want to create a setup wizard ,where the user will choose ,when installing the application , if its the server , or the client side. When the server is selected it will create the db for the app , and when client is selected , user will point to the server machine on the network and the client app will be installed with pointing at the db on the server.

I don't know if I was clear enough or too complicated while explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue with WCF. 
 I am building a WCF Host on the main server , where the terminals will comunicate to main server via WCF and the host program will do all the sql queries.